# sql date parameter in query

Tags: sql

I've got a query and I want to add parameters to calculate the moving annual (the figures for the last 12 months).  I'm trying to subtract 12 months from today, so if for instance today is 1 August 2012 then my @StartDate should be '2011-09-01' and my @EndDate should be '2012-08-31'.  So how do I change set my parameters to accommodate this?

```
declare @StartDate DATE
declare @EndDate   DATE
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(MONTH, -12, '2012-08-01')
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(MONTH, +1, '2012-08-01')
```

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... features like this is often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DECLARE
  @InputDate DATE,
  @StartDate DATE,
  @EndDate   DATE

SET
  @InputDate = '2012-08-01'

SET
  @StartDate = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @InputDate) - 11, 0)

SET
  @EndDate   = DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 12, @StartDate))
```

**EDIT:**

However, I do *not* recomend using `'2011-09-01'` to `'2012-08-31'` as a representation of a year.  Instead, use `'2011-09-01'` to `'2012-09-01'` in the following way...

```
WHERE
      table.dateField >= '2011-09-01'
  AND table.dateField <  '2012-09-01'
```

This works for all Date and DateTime data types.  Even if the value in `dateField` is 2:30pm on 31st August, this will still work.  It's a one size fits all approach and makes it *much* more difficult to make mistakes on date and time boundaries.

Comment: I used it as follows: where a.Invoice between @StartDate and EndDate
 but get the following error:  Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @wilest - Update your question to include the full table definition, your whole query, and the exact error message *(which should mention on which line the error ocurred)*.

Comment: on further investigation it was complaining about something else, thank you so much it's working now

Comment: Just another question why do you use 0 for the start date in the datediff?

Comment: @wilest - That line does `Add to date X the number of whole months that are from date X to date Y`.  Provided that `X` is the start of a month, that effectively rounds `Y` down to the start of the month.  And `0` just happens to be a convenient date that is the start of a month.  *(1st Jan 1900.)*

Answer (score 1):

This was a few years ago but still not answered properly. The poster wants to find 12 months back from today, where "today" is dynamic. All prior answers start with a hard-coded start date instead of `GETDATE()`

```
DECLARE 
@StartDate datetime,
@EndDate datetime

Set @StartDate = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())-1, MONTH(GETDATE()), DAY(GETDATE()), 0, 0, 0, 0); Use midnight or a time that matches your business case.
Set @EndDate =  DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), DAY(GETDATE()), 23, 59, 59, 0); -- modify to match the times you are looking for.

Select * from Mydbase
WHERE
      table.dateField between @StartDate and @EndDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this after your last SET command:

```
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @EndDate)
```

Or substitute the 2nd SET by:

```
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1,DATEADD(MONTH, +1, '2012-08-01'))
```

Answer (score 0):

try tiis:

```
declare @Date DATE='2012-08-05'
select convert(date,DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, @Date)-11,0)) StartDate ,
                       convert(date,DateAdd(day,-1,DateAdd(Month,1,
                       DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, @Date),0)))) EndDate
```

result:

```
StartDate       EndDate
2011-09-01  2012-08-31
```